# Getting value of dropdownlist that's added onrowdatabound asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, gridview, dynamic

I'm querying a database filling a gridview with values, also adding dropdown boxes into each cell within the dataview 'onrowdatabound' so these DDL's are populated when the gridview is populated.

I want to be able to click a button to get values from these DDL's however when the button is clicked postback happens and all the DDL's disappear and it gives me the default value for the DDL.

I assume they dissapear as they're not called on pageload (which I can't seem to do as they're called onrowdatabound)

```
<asp:GridView id="View" name="Spview" onrowdatabound="populateCellswithDDls" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
```

Adding the ddl with inside 'populateCellswithDDls' function looping each cell:

```
 e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(DDL1);
```

The next thing I've have a play with is ViewState and Sessions to save the dropdownlists on postback(Tried making sessions within 'populateCellswithDDls' function as so:

```
DropDownList DDL1 = new DropDownList();

//I've tried newSkillsMon.AutoPostBack = true; but this just removes them all too

Session.Add("ViewState", View);
Session.Add("DropdownState", DDL1);
```

I've tried all sorts do to  with viewstate and session but unsure where to use them in relation to saving states the 'onrowdatabound' population.

My button currently looks like this:

```
 protected void confirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){

                {foreach (GridViewRow row in View.Rows)

                        // if (DDL1.SelectedItem.Value != "Select Item"){

                        if (IsPostBack)
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine(DDL1.SelectedValue);
                        }
```

This just gives me X amount of "Select Item" rather than what i have selected in the DDL

What am I missing, where would I add these sessions to keep the ddl's created by onrowdatabound?

Thanks

Comment: Are you binding your gridview in page_load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating dynamic controls, you need to recreate them on every Page Load and that includes a PostBack. So start with binding the GridView data outside an `IsPostBack` check.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        //normally you would bind here
    }

    //but now bind grid every page load
    GridView1.DataSource = Common.LoadFromDB();
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Now in the RowDataBound event make sure the DropDownList has an `ID`

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //check if the row is a datarow
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //create a dropdownlist and assign an ID
        DropDownList DDL1 = new DropDownList();
        DDL1.ID = "DDL1";

        //add some dummy listitems
        DDL1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem() { Text = "A", Value = "A" });
        DDL1.Items.Insert(1, new ListItem() { Text = "B", Value = "B" });
        DDL1.Items.Insert(2, new ListItem() { Text = "C", Value = "C" });

        //add the control to the row
        e.Row.Cells[0].Controls.Add(DDL1);
    }
}
```

Now you can get the value from the correct row on a button click.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //find the dropdownlist in the correct row and cast it back to one
    DropDownList DDL1 = GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("DDL1") as DropDownList;

    //display the result
    Label1.Text = DDL1.SelectedValue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this looks great but my data source is a datatable within the onrowdatabound function - how would I append this to the control within the grid view.. I don't seem to be able to call the value within the function, I might try a static variable..

Comment: The datasource for the DDL is irrelevant for the working of this snippet. But if you use a DataTable declare it outside the method, check if it is null or empty, if empty fill once and then you can reuse it in every row.

Comment: Edit: static works however the first click of the DDL does nothing, second click does, which is weird'

Comment: Add `DDL1.AutoPostBack = true` to the databound method.

Comment: Already is true, think its something to do with databinding in page load before the sql is queried?

Comment: Maybe, but difficult to tell without all the code. Does settings the `DDL1.selectevalue = ` help?

Comment: Also, now my databind is in my pageload all the data is wrong in the view depending on what I choose in the DDL

Comment: Yeah theres alot of code to share, appreciate your help - i'll have a look at that.

Answer (score 0):

Something that might work for you instead of trying sessions is to use hiddenfields.
Make a hidden field for each dropdown location and then use javascript to populate the hidden fields with the dropdown values. (Possibly wanting some server side validation on submission)

Something like this with jQuery:

```
$(".dropdowns").on("change", function () {
    $(this).closest('input:hidden').val($(this).val());
});
```

And in your confirmation:

```
if (HF_HiddenField1.Value != "Select Item")
```

Comment: I didn't actually think about using jQuery, i'll look into using this  and let you know thanks